# coerce labelled variables to numeric after recoding

Tags: r, import, recode

Is there a simpler way in the haven or labelled packages to turn labelled variables into numeric variables?

The following code illustrates my problem.  After important from an sav file, every variable is a labelled variable.  Some are, originally, numeric variables, with 98 and 99 as missing values. So I have to recode those to set to NA, but then I have to coerce the recoded variable to numeric with as.numeric()

Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
#Load libraries
library(devtools)
library(dplyr)
library(car)
#Install package with data
install_github('sjkiss/LSIRM')
#Load library
library(LSIRM)
#Loda dataset
data(ces)
#show variable of interest
table(ces$PES15_74)
#Get variable labels
variable_labels<-lapply(ces, function(x) attr(x, 'label'))
#Get value labels
value_labels<-lapply(ces, function(x) attr(x, 'labels'))
#Show class of variable of interest
class(ces$PES15_74)
#show variable and value labels
ces$PES15_74 
attr(ces$PES15_74, 'labels') #Note 98 and 99 should be missing values 
#Show mean
mean(ces$PES15_74, na.rm=T)
#Recode out missing values
ces$tv<-recode(ces$PES15_74, "98:99=NA")
#Show class
class(ces$tv)
#Try with as.factor.result=F
ces$tv2<-recode(ces$PES15_74, "98:99=NA", as.factor.result=F)
#show class
class(ces$tv2)
#coerce to numeric
ces$tv<-as.numeric(ces$tv)
#show mean after coercion
mean(ces$tv, na.rm=T)
#show mean uncoerced
mean(ces$PES15_74, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: If you had regular numeric variables you can change 98 and 99 to NA easily. Why not just convert the necessary columns to numeric, then worry about particular numbers after everything is set?

Comment: since you say you have to coerce to numeric, I assume that `ces$PES15_74` is a character? then you could try `type.convert(c(1:5, '98','99'), na.strings = c('98','99'))`

Answer (score 2):

You can try my package [expss](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expss/index.html). But it has slightly different implementation of class "labelled" so there is conversion in the code below (or you can read *.sav file with expss::read_spss).

```
library(LSIRM)
data(ces)
library(expss)

### change class "labelled" to c("labelled", "numeric")
for (each in colnames(ces)){
    if ("labelled" %in% class(ces[[each]])){
        class(ces[[each]]) = c("labelled", "numeric")
    }
}

### calculations
fre(ces$PES15_74)
ces$tv = if_val(ces$PES15_74, 98:99 ~ NA)
fre(ces$tv)
cro(ces$PES15_74, ces$tv)
mean_col(ces$tv)
```